# Continuity between Pretty Cure series

Tags: pretty-cure

It's "common knowledge" that each Pretty Cure series takes place in its own continuity.  From my limited experience with the franchise I've already seen two contradictions with that idea.

1. Kenta Hoshino, a supporting character in Splash Star, made an appearance in the previous series, Max Heart.  He was even slightly younger in it.
2. In both Splash Star and Heartcatch, Cures have been shown to be a long-standing order of warriors.

What's the official stance on continuity?  Is this "common knowledge" based on official statements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Wikipedia:

> There are currently ten anime television series in the franchise, two of which are direct sequels to their previous series. Each series of Pretty Cure has its own story and motifs. Each of the series also feature manga adaptations, which are illustrated by Futago Kamikita and published in Kodansha's Nakayoshi magazine.

According to prettycure.wikia.com:

> [Splash Star] is the first spinoff or "sequel" from the original Futari wa Pretty Cure, with a continuity reboot.

It seems that the direct sequels follow continuity but that there is only overlap between the non-direct-sequels, rather than complete continuity.

Comment: That's a shame, I was hoping that the series would have stronger continuity.  Still, good answer. :)